# Using sh with bash

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am using ubuntu OS and my default shell is the bash. However, still I can use the Bourne shell ( sh) for writing the shell scripts, through including :

```
# !/bin/sh
```

How can I still use sh although I am using the bash? Is this because the bash is an improvement of the Bourne shell and hence it is backward compatible with sh ?

Comment: When you use  the sh shebang, bash behave posix'ly

Comment: Yup, not all distros use "another shell" for `sh`. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html

Comment: `# !/bin/sh ` is *not* a shebang. `#!/bin/sh ` or `#! /bin/sh ` would be. The trailing space is fine, but the space between `#` and `!` definitely breaks the magic. The line you posted is just a comment. Then the following applies: [*Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/108618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Debian nowadays, `sh` in Ubuntu is actually a symlink to Dash. You can check it with `ls -l`:

```
pg1@TREX:~$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Dec 10  2020 /bin/sh -> dash
```

"Improvement" is a rather imprecise word; Bash is more an extended version of Bourne shell. Dash is not Bash -compatible, but Bash tries to stay mostly POSIX-compliant; thus compliant with Dash. Note, mostly - every now and then you see the word *bashism* used about elements in a script which aren't POSIX-compliant.

Quoting from LWN.net article [A tale of two shells: bash or dash](https://lwn.net/Articles/343924/):

*"The major reason to switch the default shell was efficiency. bash is an excellent full-featured shell appropriate for interactive use; indeed, it is still the default login shell. However, it is rather large and slow to start up and operate by comparison with dash. A large number of shell instances are started as part of the Ubuntu boot process. Rather than change each of them individually to run explicitly under /bin/dash, a change which would require significant ongoing maintenance and which would be liable to regress if not paid close attention, the Ubuntu core development team felt that it was best simply to change the default shell.*

*The Debian EeePC project also notes that dash provides faster boot times."*

Answer (score 1):

The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) tells your shell (in this case bash) what to execute the remainder of the file with.  There are tricky things you can do with it but I won't go into that here.

It does not tell bash to behave differently.  As an example, if it pointed to `/usr/bin/perl`, perl would attempt to execute the file.

@Peregrino69 answer has some nice information in it about `sh` actually being `dash` in Ubuntu.  I highly suggest you read that too.

When you have this `#!/bin/sh` line, everything beneath it will indeed execute with sh and not bash.  This is why POSIX operating systems (mostly) do not need file extensions (Windows) or resource forks (classic mac).
This behavior can be both good and bad.  For instance, it only supports hard coded path names which becomes a problem if ***whizbangOSLinux++*** put sh in `/usr/bin/sh`

I believe that the shebang can be used to execute darn near anything to include binary data following the ASCII but it has been years since I have seen that trickery and don't know if it is still supported.

Comment: Thank you so much